# Javascript comment stripper

Tags: javascript, comments

I'm looking for some tool to remove cooments from Javascript sources. I was able to Google some, but none of them satisfied the following requirement: **Everything else should be left as it is, in particular white space is not removed, BUT if a comment takes a whole line, the line is removed too**.

Shortly, I want to be able to go from a nicely formatted source with comments to an equally formatted source without comments. Lines which only contain comments are removed, and traliing comments are removed together with the trailing spaces. All the rest is left as it is.

Do you know any tool for such a job?

**EDIT**: I try to be more specific. Using regular expressions is not possible, as the characters `//` or `/*` can also appear inside strings, regular expressions and so on.

The tool should take this input

```
var a = true;

//the following code is every useful
var b = 2;//really, really useful
 /**
Never, ever do this
var c = 3;
  */
var d = 4;
```

and give this output

```
var a = true;

var b = 2;
var d = 4;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to do this? Why not fully compress, if you are about to change the source anyway?

Comment: It is for me. Sometimes I find more readable the source without all comments that I left, in particular those for automatically generating documentation.

Comment: If you use Gulp, https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-strip-comments should be useful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's some code I whipped up:
Check it out: [here](https://gist.github.com/SudoPlz/037b229ea53717bbcac1)

Also [here](http://trinithis.awardspace.com/commentStripper/stripper.html) is an example of my code you can test RIGHT NOW in a webpage

Here's one I didn't write that could be handy, though his code will fail on certain regex literals: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/removing-comments-in-javascript/

EDIT:
The code I wrote is as is. I am not updating it as it is something I wrote when I was a teenager and rather new to programming. If there is a bug, you can fix it.

Comment: It leaves a lot of white space instead of comments, like other tools that I have tried. I'd like to have it remove lines consisting of comments altogether.

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to modify the code to do what you want...

Comment: It becomes messier, since the original code parses by character, and to do what I want, one need to keep track of lines too. But I decided to accept this anyway, and make the necessary modifications.

Comment: @Andrea: Updated the code to remove the last line in a file if that line only contains comments.

Comment: your code is crappy as sh1t and one has to ctrl-alt-del his firefox to close the window because the "do you want to stop this script" window pop-ups repeatedly. no offense.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: My code does not call alert or create popups... look at the source code.

Comment: @ThomasEding I didn't say that it creates popups. I said that it enters in an endless loop and the browser asks me "do you want to stop the script?" and as soon as I say yes, it goes again immediately into the endless loop which makes it impossible to close the browser

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: Ah, I misread it. My code is as is. If anyone wants to debug it, they can go ahead, but I'm not going to revisit it.

Comment: Is it me or does the one on james.padolsey.com have a key issue in that it assumes all forward slashes are the start of a regular expression literal?  What about if you have division '/'???  Can someone think of a way around this?

Comment: Does not remove my comments unfortunately.

Comment: The first link does not work for the following string: var z/=3;z="/ /*";z="*/";

Comment: @ThomasEding I'm curious how you wrote this code or what inspired you. It's incredibly hard to follow.  Did you copy and paste stuff from different projects?

Answer (score 10):

Use Google's [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) with WHITE_SPACE_ONLY and PRETTY_PRINT -- the only thing that it will do is remove the comments (Unless of course you don't format your code in the way that PRETTY_PRINT does.)

It turns this:

```
// This function alerts a name
function hello(name) {
    /**
    * One lone
    * multi-line
    * comment
    */
    alert('Hello, ' + name);
}
hello('New user');
```

Into this:

```
function hello(name) {
  alert("Hello, " + name)
}
hello("New user");
```

Comment: This is almost what I want, but not quite. It removes all new lines, regardless if there where some in the original code. I would like to only remove lines entirely composed of comments, not intentional new lines.

Comment: It also messes with other things, for instance it replaces my tabs with two spaces. I need a tool that does not come in my way, it only should remove comments.

Comment: that's super awesome ,thank you so much

Comment: @Andrea, depending on your editor you could reformat your your code by using a JS format plugin or a JS format site like https://beautifier.io/

Answer (score 2):

Found a pretty sweet solution here: http://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment

**Excerpt:**

> Now we just need to modify the comment end to allow any number of *:

```
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

> We now have a regular expression that we can paste into text editors that support regular expressions. Finding our comments is a matter of pressing the find button. You might be able to simplify this expression somewhat for your particular editor. For example, in some regular expression implementations, [^] assumes the [\r\n] and all the [\r\n] can be removed from the expression.
>
> This is easy to augment so that it will also find // style comments:

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)
```

Be sure to read the caveats, however, as this will remove comments from with comments, or can uncomment commented code improperly.  Worked perfectly for me, however :-)

Answer (score 2):

Library [decomment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decomment) does exactly what you described:

> Everything else should be left as it is, in particular white space is not removed, BUT if a comment takes a whole line, the line is removed too.

And it also supports JSON5, JavaScript ES6, CSS and HTML.

Comment: It works badly under windows with: 
;(function() {
  // *** LOGGER CODE *** //

Comment: @Vladimir could you, please clarify, or log the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use babel `"comments": false` to achieve this. I have wrote a demo to for `the-super-tiny-compiler`, please check https://github.com/gengjiawen/the-super-tiny-compiler.

Run `npm run remove-comments` after install deps.

Answer (score 1):

naive one liner stripper:

```
var noComments = text.replace(/\/\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*\//g, '').replace(/\/\/.*/gm, '');
```

DISCLAIMER:

"naive" means:

1. it strips across everywhere, say if you have:

   ```
   var a = "/*";
   someImportantLogicHere();
   var b = "*/";
   ```

   then you will get

   ```
   var a = "";
   ```
2. order in which you apply these regexps matters, you will get different results applying it in different order

but for 95% other cases it's simple and paractical

Answer (score 0):

#### Just a small insight that might help you make your complex regular expression much simpler..

<sub>*feel free to later apply any of the tips in answers above..*</sub>

```
var text = ".................."; //assuming staring point

........

text = text
.replace(/\r/g,"##R##")
.replace(/\n/g,"##N##")

.replace(/\/\*(.*)\*\//g,"")

.replace(/##R##/g,"\r")
.replace(/##N##/g,"\n")
```

applying a little (independent) replacement of `\r` and `\n` will simplify your regex **A LOT!**,

> originally even with `g` and `m` modifiers (global and "greedy" flags), you still won't succeed removing the comments (unless you custom-build a  "character-walker" loop, or run the same reg-ex multiple times...) *this is due some characteristics of the regular-expression matching left in limbo since ECMAScript 4 ([ECMA-262](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Versions))*

---

<sub>**What smart thing are doing here that is worth mentioning ?**</sub>

This way we apply a nifty little trick known in Discrete mathematics(languages and grammar) as "replacement outside of our grammar", I'm using this unconventionally to "protect" the `\r` and `\n` areas in the text without actually applying too much computational-power to process them (as in cut/assemble etc..)

Here it's kind of a gamble since, essentially, `##R##` and `##N##` (although not so common), might be an existing phrase, but this is not an issue since the replacement can be infinitesimally-more complex.

*In short,*
The regular-expressions will be simpler,
The regular-replacements will work as intended without that whitespace-bug..
And `\n` and `\r` will be restored to their original placement, intact.