# PHP Regex ignore commented lines

Tags: php, regex

I have a REGEX from [github](https://github.com/kevva/import-regex/blob/master/index.js) which seems to work fine, however it won't handle commented lines.

```php
$regex = '/(?:@import)(?:\\s)?(?:(?:(?:\\()(["\'])?(?:[^"\')]+)\\1(?:\\))|(["\'])(?:.+)\\2)(?:[A-Z\\s])*)+(?:;)/';
```

This REGEX will be tested on content like this:

```php
$content =
'// Layout & components // this should fail

@import "variables", "mixins"; // this should validate
// @import "tools", "functions"; // this should fail

// @import "media/vendor/bootstrap/scss/root"; // this should fail
@import "media/vendor/bootstrap/scss/reboot"; // this should validate
@import "../../../media/vendor/bootstrap/scss/tools"; // this should validate

@import url("some.css"); // this should fail
// @import url("some.css"); // this should fail
//@import url("some.css"); // this should fail
// @import some; // this should fail
//@import some; // this should fail
//@import"some"; // this should fail
//@importsome; // this should fail
```

In the above example, the first line will be ignored because it doesn't have '@import' but the second line still passes (will not be ignored) because it's not a handled case.

I've setup a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pHewhp/1) which doesn't work live, however it does work on my local environment.

**What I need**:

- I'm thinking I should add something like `(^\\n?!:(\/\/))` at the beginning but I don't know if that's going to work or it won't do something else.
- This REGEX would work with cases like `@import url("bar.css");` I would like to remove this case, make it only work with `@import "bar.scss".
- Some suggest I should strip comments before applying this REGEX, I tested this `preg_replace("/^\\/{2}.*|\\/\\*.*\\*\\/$/", '', $content)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573253/remove-all-real-javascript-comments-in-php) but it breaks my code, so I would like to know what you think it's best.

Appreciate any reply. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which includes sample input that contains some of the trickier occurrences, then show your exact desired output from the sample input.

Comment: I've added a link to regex101, it's all there.

Comment: Volunteers shouldn't have to link chase or rely on an external resource (which may die one day in the future) to fully understand your question.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The question includes no details of what exactly you're trying to match and/or substitute. It'll be loads more helpful if you added some sample inputs and the outputs you desire, along with the code you've used so far and what it's not doing.

Comment: I added a sample code. Please check.

Comment: "Works fine" shouldn't necessitate a question. But why not just strip comments before the match step? Also: use the /x flag.

Comment: I don't know how to strip comments. I mean from `//` to `\n` or `/*` to `*/`.

Comment: Guys, I've updated the question, please check and advise. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you double escaping all characters? `\\/` means 1 backslash and 1 slash, `\\*` means 0 or more backslashes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use

```php
$regex = "/^\\s*@import\\s+(\"|').*\\1\\s*[^;]*;.*$/m";
```

<sup>(You can try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/3gou5o/2)</sup>

This does only match for a import rule without anything than whitespace before the line start and nothing but a semicolon after the import url. Note that this also does match invalid imports.

Examples:

```
// Layout & components                               -> does not match
// @import "media/vendor/bootstrap/scss/root";       -> does not match
@import url("media/vendor/bootstrap/scss/reboot");   -> does not match
@import url("media/vendor/bootstrap/scss/type");     -> does not match
@import "media/vendor/bootstrap/scss/images" screen; -> matches
@import "media/vendor/bootstrap/scss/containers";    -> matches
@import 'media/vendor/bootstrap/scss/components' ;   -> matches
@import "images", "screen";                          -> matches

@import "this/is"/invalid";                          -> matches
```

Comment: I edited my answer. It machtes all the cases you posted.

Comment: I forgot to mention about cases like `@import "../../../media/vendor/bootstrap/scss/root";`, please check.