# Remove comments from string with JavaScript using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There is some string (for example, 's'):

```
import 'lodash';
// TODO import jquery
//import 'jquery';

/*
Some very important comment
*/
```

How can I remove all comments from 's' string? Should I use some Regexp for it? I don't know.

Comment: The code you show is the content of string?

Comment: Yes it is, its string value

Comment: A regex will get most instances but see this (http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/removing-comments-in-javascript/) for more insights

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577767/javascript-comment-stripper

Comment: UglifyJS has the ability to remove comments. https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2

Comment: 2019: I write good solution for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57809519/1919821)

Comment: Specifically regarding comments in html (which covers JS comments). Could be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64617472/3799617

Answer (score 24):

The [one from @MarcoS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37051915/1134119) won't work in several cases...

Below is my solution:

```js
str.replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|(?<=[^:])\/\/.*|^\/\/.*/g,'');
```

Removing comments from a string:

```js
function removeComments(string){
    //Takes a string of code, not an actual function.
    return string.replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|(?<=[^:])\/\/.*|^\/\/.*/g,'').trim();//Strip comments
}
const commentedcode = `
alert('hello, this code has comments!')//An alert
/* A block comment here */
// A single line comment on a newline
`;
console.log(removeComments(commentedcode));
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tkOHrE/1):

[image: regexp examples]

**EDIT**: I changed the formula to avoid issues with links ([see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051797/remove-comments-from-string-with-javascript-using-javascript/59094308?noredirect=1#comment133180151_59094308))

Comment: Might you be able to edit your answer to show a full JS function?

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch I have edited the answer to include a full function!

Comment: `\`const x = '// hello \n/*hello*/'\`.replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|\/\/.*/g,'');` will get `const x = '\n'`

Comment: This also removes // when found inside strings which messes with e.g. urls like this "http://.."

Comment: Indeed @Johncl … I updated the expression.

Comment: Adds blank space in place of comments.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use a RegExp, you could use this one:

```
/(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[^*]*)/
```

This should strip both `// ... \n` style comments and `/* ... */` style comments.

#### Full working code:

```
var stringWithoutComments = s.replace(/(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[^*]*)/g, '');
console.log(stringWithoutComments);
```

#### Test with multiline strings:

```
var s = `before
/* first line of comment
   second line of comment */
after`;
var stringWithoutComments = s.replace(/(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[^*]*)/g, '');
console.log(stringWithoutComments);
```

outputs:

```
before

after
```

Comment: @MarkoS, can you provide me with full JS code for it?

Comment: I got the error "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/*([^*]|[
]|(*+([^*/]|[
])))**+/)|(//.*)/: Nothing to repeat" @MarkoS

Comment: You're right, sorry... Just updated answer with simpler, shorter and always-working code... :-)

Comment: sorry, but your answer doesn't support multiline /**/ comment, can you add it? Thanks!

Comment: Just tested, it seems working with multiline comments, too... Which is the test which is failing on you?

Comment: What about this one: `// console.log(1*2)`

Comment: `"ok = '// hi';".replace(/(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[^*]*)/g, '');` will give `"ok = '"`

Comment: This also removes // when inside strings so it messes with e.g. url strings "http://..."

Answer (score 5):

```js
console.log(`

     var myStr = 'я! This \\'seems\\' to be a // comment'; // but this is actually the real comment.
    /* like this one */ var butNot = 'this "/*one*/"'; // but this one and /* this one */
    /* and */ var notThis = "one '//but' \\"also\\""; /* // this one */
    `
    
    // 1) replace "/" in quotes with non-printable ASCII '\1' char
    .replace(/("([^\\"]|\\")*")|('([^\\']|\\')*')/g, (m) => m.replace(/\//g, '\1'))
    
    // 2) clear comments
    .replace(/(\/\*[^*]+\*\/)|(\/\/[^\n]+)/g, '')
    
    // 3) restore "/" in quotes
    .replace(/\1/g, '/')

);
```

Comment: doesn't handle comments with nothing after them, such as `//` on a line by itself, but I really like the support for ignoring comments inside quotes.  If you replace your step two, with the accepted answer, this is superior.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this *RegEX* to match all comments *(Supporting Russia Symbols. | Latin or Cyrillic | )*.

```
(\/\*[\wа-я\'\s\r\n\*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[\wа-я\s\'\;]*)|(\<![\-\-\s\wа-я\>\/]*\>)
```

---

*RegEX Parts :*

```
Part1: (\/\*[\wа-я\'\s\r\n\*]*\*\/) for comments style: /*   .....   */ 

Part2: (\/\/[\wа-я\s\'\;]*)         for comments style: //   .....

Part3: (\<![\-\-\s\wа-я\>\/]*\>)    for comments style: <!-- .....  -->
```

[***Updated Regex101 DEMO***](https://regex101.com/r/bP2lX0/2)

[***Updated JsFiddle DEMO***](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/xezeffge/1/) *, Supporting **Russia symbols** in comments*

---

```css
textarea{
  width:300px;
  height:120px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="code">
import 'lodash';
// TODO импортируем auth provider
//import 'jquery';

/*
Some very important comment
*/
</textarea>
<br />
<button onclick="removeAllComments()">Remove All Comments</button>

<script>
    function removeAllComments(){
        var str = document.getElementById('code').innerHTML.replace(/(\/\*[\wа-я\'\s\r\n\*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[\wа-я\s\'\;]*)|(\<![\-\-\s\wа-я\>\/]*\>)/ig, "");
        document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = str;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide me full JS code? With testing of course, because it doesn't work for me

Comment: @malcoauri ok, i've updated [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/ss6L9dwa/) and snippet on my answer

Comment: @malcoauri Have you tried my last updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/xezeffge/1/) in previous comment ? is there any problem with it ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
comment1 = ' I dont like oneline comment. to parsing. // like this comment.'
comment2 = ' also i hate multiple line comment
    /*
    like
    this.*/'

comment1.replace(/\s*(?:\/\/).*?$/gm , '')
// but you can't delete multiple line commet with regular grammar. like comment2
```

RegExp is base on regular grammar. it means regular grammar parser is a finate state machine and can't save state so regexp can't delete like multiple comment it can only oneline comment.

if you want to delete multiple line comment, then you have to write parser. or use something else not regexp.

Answer (score 1):

i find this very useful and small solution

```js
const word = ` 
      /**  @page type
      *       page    = ".page-body"
      *       popup   = ".pop-up-body"
      *       overlay = ".overlay-body" // new classes
      * 
      */
     
 
    return {
      "static" : '.page-body, .overlay-body, .pop-up-body, .card-wrapper { margin : 5px !important } .row { padding: 5px !important}'
    }
  `
console.log(word.replace(/\/*[^*]*.[^]*\//g,''))
```